# Play framework Sharing common variables not found in sub project (module)

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.0, sbt

I have multi module (subProject) project. which has structure like that

```
my_app  
|__app  
|__conf  
|__public  
|__project  
|  |__Common.scala  
|__modules  
|  |__admin
|     |__src/test/scala      
|     |__build.sbt  
|  |__product
|     |__src/test/scala      
|     |__build.sbt  
|__build.sbt
```

I want to put common variable like 'Version', 'organization' in the common place and want to share between all modules (sub projects).

Therefore i used the approach mentioned here

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/SBTSubProjects

created my_app/project/Common.scala and add common variable in it , so will be automatically available in each modules

the Common.scala looks like this

```
import sbt._
import Keys._


object Common {
  val settings: Seq[Setting[_]] = Seq(
    organization := "com.abc",
    version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  )
}
```

they have been accessed in sub-project admin/build.sbt like this

```
name := "admin"

Common.settings

lazy val admin = (project in file("."))
  .enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean, GitVersioning, BuildInfoPlugin, DebianPlugin)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  cache,
  evolutions,
  filters,
  javaWs,
  "junit" % "junit" % "4.12" % "test"
)
```

"Common.settings" is not found in admin/build.sbt, its read underline.(see image)

[image]

please help, how to make 'Common.setting' available in admin/buil.sbt.

IDE: Intellij